# implement stack in c++

Tags: c++, stack

How can I code a stack in C++? I have tried this myself as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define max 10
class stack{

private:
    int arr[max];
    int top;
public:
    stack(){

        top=-1;//empty initialy stack 

    }

    void push(int i){
        top++;
         if (top<max){

             arr[top]=i;
         }
         else{
             cout<<"stack full"<<endl;
             top--;
    }

    }
int pop(){

    if (top==-1){
         cout<<"stack is emphty");
     return NULL;
    }
    else{
        int data=arr[top];
        arr[top]=NULL;
        top--;

     return data;
}
}
bool empty(){

     return (top==-1);

}
};
int main(){

    stack a;
    a.push(12);
    a.push(30);
    a.push(23);
    a.push(42);
    a.push(100);
    while (!a.empty()){
        a.pop();



    }



     return 0;
}
```

But I get the following errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: stack_implementations, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stak_implementation.cpp
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\stack_implementations\stak_implementation.cpp(31): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\stack_implementations\stak_implementation.cpp(34): error C2059: syntax error : 'else'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\stack_implementations\stak_implementation.cpp(34): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\stack_implementations\stak_implementation.cpp(42): error C2628: 'stack' followed by 'bool' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\stack_implementations\stak_implementation.cpp(44): error C2065: 'top' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\stack_implementations\stak_implementation.cpp(31): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\stack_implementations\stak_implementation.cpp(47): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\stack_implementations\stak_implementation.cpp(47): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\stack_implementations\stak_implementation.cpp(47): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\stack_implementations\stak_implementation.cpp(56): error C2039: 'empty' : is not a member of 'stack'
1>          c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\stack_implementations\stak_implementation.cpp(4) : see declaration of 'stack'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\stack_implementations\stak_implementation.cpp(56): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Is this for a school assignment? A good idea might be to make the indentation of the code better for ease of reading.

Comment: don't forget commententing and u can also use c++ const too, maybe you can later as an extra program it as an template and throw Exceptions if the stack is full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will be less error prone, and clearer to read, if you only change state (variables, members etc) when you need to. So, if you rewrite the push function into

```
void push(int i){
     if (top<max-1){
         arr[++top]=i;
     }
     else{
         cout<<"stack full"<<endl;
     }
}
```

it'll be cleaner. Also, const is type safe, whereas #define is not, so `const int max=10` is preferrable to `#define max 10`.

Since the stack is a stack of integers, NULL in your assignment `arr[top]=NULL` will be cast into an int and the assignment will be interpreted as `arr[top]=0`. You could remove the assignment altogether, since the element is outside the stack once popped, and thus it doesn't matter whether it's zero or not.

BTW, I'd use `top` as a pointer to the next available stack item rather than a pointer to the last used one, in order to avoid having a reserved 'non pointer' value of -1.

Answer (score 6):

You've got a stray close bracket on line 31;

```
    cout<<"stack is emphty");
```

Fix that and see how many of the other "errors" disappear.

Don't worry about not spotting it straight away. It's happened to me many times. You're convinced that something serious is wrong with your code so you fail to spot the trivial typos and spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

You have an unbalanced parenthesis on line 31, as reported by your compiler.

```
cout<<"stack is emphty");
```

Please read those compiler errors carefully.  They usually pin-point the problem right away.